# How can I found a source of HTTP request in Wireshark?

Tags: http, wireshark, ubuntu

There are weird requests to/from the AWS:

[image]

and another one to/from 177.143.198.104.bc.googleusercontent.com:

[image]

( http://whois.domaintools.com/177.143.198.104 )

I use Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop, web browsers are turned off. How can I found a source? I mean, what program/script does it run.

Comment: This has been discussed previously: https://askubuntu.com/questions/993253/is-networkmanager-sending-http-requests-to-googleusercontent-com.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux the command

netstat -anp

Will list all network connections and will include the ip, port , and program name

So in wireshark you can find the ip and port for the web request

Then run netstat and search for that ip and port to find the program using it